# how to access a linear layout of the activity_main.xml inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-layout

this is my activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/banner_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/contact_card_line_color"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/no_internet_connection"
            android:textColor="@color/contact_card_initial_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/banner_text_size" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/banner_layout">

    </FrameLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

In my main activity, I do

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_launch_view);

  fragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_holder, fragment).commit();
```

In my fragment,

1) could not see the no internet connection text by default
2) I can access them , no runtime error, but could not see the text.

Comment: The reason behind is you placed the textView before framelayout so that the framelayout hides the textView.To solve this problem place textView after the frame layout.

Comment: use interface for any event for linear layout from fragment

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a relative layout, your match parent framelayout overlaps with your textview so you need to either change it to linearlayout or use layout_below tag to your banner layout.